# Как сделать так, чтобы при потере интернет соединения "кнопка обновить" показывалась всегда?

Tags: java, android

Есть приложение, которое воспроизводит онлайн радио.

При сворачивании приложения или при отключении интернета выходит внизу сообщение **"Нет интернет соединения!"** и кнопка **"RETRY"**. Спустя пару секунд это сообщение с кнопкой пропадает и не появляется., и соответственно окно со списком станций не обновляется. Как сделать так, чтобы это **окно с кнопкой RETRY** висело всегда, или до тех пор, пока интернет не появится и обновило мне активити автоматически. Подскажите пожалуйста, где и что заменить в коде?? Я еще не совсем разбираюсь в этом...

**P.S:** Если важно, то список со станциями находится не в приложении, а грузится с сервера с помощью **json** файла.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (connDetector.checkInternetConnection()) {

    }else {
        showCustomToast("Нет интернет соединения!");
        return;
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

и

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    pos =getPosition();
    Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + getPosition());
    if (connDetector.checkInternetConnection()) {
        String trackId = null;
        String trackTitle = null;
        String trackImageUrl = null;
        if (mArrTrackList != null) {
            rl_musiccontorl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            card_view_musiccontorl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            trackId = mArrTrackList.get(pos).getId();
            trackTitle = mArrTrackList.get(pos).getTitle();
            trackImageUrl = mArrTrackList.get(pos).getArtwork_url();
            sharedPref.saveTrackId(trackId);
            sharedPref.saveTrackTitle(trackTitle);
            sharedPref.saveTrackImageUrl(trackImageUrl);
            HomeActivity.musicSrv.setSongDetails(mArrTrackList, pos);
            HomeActivity.musicSrv.playSong();

        }
        resetplayer();
    } else {
        showCustomToast(getResources().getString("Нет интернет соединения!);
        finish();
    }
}
```

и

```
   private void setNoNetwork() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    card_view_network.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    textView_title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    listView_Category.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    card_view_musiccontorl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Snackbar.make(parentPanel, getString(R.string.network_error), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
            .setAction("RETRY", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    getRequest();
                }
            }).show();

}
```

[image: снизу то самое окошко, которое само исчезает.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как сделать так, чтобы это окно с кнопкой RETRY висело всегда

Это Ваше «окно» представляет из себя не что иное, как `SnackBar`. Для того, чтобы `SnackBar` не скрывался автоматически, при его создании третьем параметром необходимо передать константу `Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE`:

```
Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, "My awesome snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).
```

Для того, чтобы скрыть `SnackBar`, достаточно вызвать метод `dismiss()`:

```
snackBar.dismiss();
```

PS. Название метода у Вас плохое, говорите `showCustomToast(...)`, а показываете `SnackBar`.